# How to configure the execution step in jvm-parallel plugin? when we want to run scenarios parallel

Tags: selenium, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I want to run my scripts parallel so I have added the `cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin` to my pom file. At the `<execution>` step I get the following error,

```
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: com.github.temyers:cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin:4.2.0:generateRunners (execution: generateRunners, phase: generate-test-sources)
```

Does anyone know what is causing the issue?

Comment: And if I run my pom.xml I am not able to see 2 different browser windows able to see only single browser

Comment: can you provide your POM to see?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error. Here is an edited snippet of my pom. Please let me know if you would like more than this.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.temyers</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generateRunners</id>
                    <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generateRunners</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <glue>com.myclientname.element.loanage</glue>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-test-sources</outputDirectory>
                        <featuresDirectory>src/test/resources/features</featuresDirectory>
                        <cucumberOutputDir>${project.build.directory}/JSON</cucumberOutputDir>
                        <format>json</format>
                        <!--<tags>${cucumber.options}</tags>-->
                        <strict>true</strict>
                        <monochrome>true</monochrome>
                            <tags>"@BusinessProcess,@B-63033_loanage_scenario1,@B-63033_loanage_scenario2,@B-63033_loanage_scenario3,@B-63033_loanage_scenario4"</tags>
                        <useTestNG>false</useTestNG>
                        <namingScheme>simple</namingScheme>
                        <parallelScheme>FEATURE</parallelScheme>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```